# Creating array from database row entries in specific column of database and using for a foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a database with multiple entries. One specific column of entries I am interested in is called `sample_group`. If there are 10 rows of entries in `sample_group`, I am trying to create a array of the unique entries using PHP.

For example, the entries would be `"food", "food", "water", "food", "swabs", "swabs", "swabs", "food", "water", "water"`and after creating an array should be: `array("food", "water", "swabs")`.

Here is my attempted code, it sort of works but the array has an empty entry at the end:

```
 $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id;";
  $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3); 
$group_array = '';
  while ($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
    $group_array .= $input['sample_group'] . ',';
  }
  $group_array2 = array_filter(array_unique(explode(',', $group_array)));
```

And then the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($group_array2 as $group) {
//do something
}
```

Can anybody please push me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you save your sample_group as comma separated values?

Comment: why not push to array within the while loop and check if value exists already?

Comment: No, it is just one word such as "food" in each row of the database in that column.

Comment: @roelofco are you only using the `sample_group` value from the query or are you doing something with the other data too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be much simpler if you made `$group_array` an actual array:

```
$group_array = array();
while ($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
    $group_array[] = $input['sample_group'];
}
$group_array = array_unique($group_array);
foreach ($group_array as $group) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: After the array was made, is it better to use a while or foreach loop?

Comment: @roelofco a foreach is generally my preferred solution

Comment: For some reason, and probably not bacause of the array creation, the `foreach` loop is not working. I have a SQL query in the `foreach` loop and the `$group` is a filter variable... Could I be missing a step?

Comment: @roelofco you could put a `print_r($group_array);` before the `foreach` to verify that it contained what you expected; if it was empty it probably means the query failed for some reason. Otherwise, without seeing the code inside the `foreach` loop it's hard to tell what might be the problem

Comment: this is what I am getting `Array ( [0] => Water [1] => Food [2] => Swab ) 1`

Comment: @roelofco that's good - the first part of the code is working properly. It sounds like the code in the `foreach` loop has some problems. I suggest you ask another question to get some help on that.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to accept your answer, because it is consistent with the rest of my code, however in the future I will apply the suggestions and method of the answer by @Tim Biegeleisen.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest just doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` on the MySQL side:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT sample_group FROM samples_database WHERE order_id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $order_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $group_array[] = $row['sample_group'];
    }
}
```

Note: You should ideally use a prepared statement when building your SQL query, and avoid concatenation.  I have attempted to provide code which uses a prepared statement.

Also, I replaced your `SELECT *` (all columns) with just `SELECT sample_group`.  The reason for this is that for one thing, selecting all columns when your script only needs one of them wastes network bandwidth, and might hurt performance.  Another reason is that `SELECT *` makes it ambiguous about *which* columns your script really needs to use.

Comment: This is good as long as OP doesn't want any of the other values in his original query

Comment: @Nick You're right, and I know that...just trying to avoid a `SELECT *` which is generally an evil thing.

Comment: Indeed, there should be a `SELECT *` hammer! :-)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why would `SELECT *` be bad?

Comment: @roelofco I don't reckon you to be ignorant at all actually.  `SELECT *` is generally frowned upon, because then it isn't clear _which_ columns your PHP script was actually asking for.  Sometimes, you get away with it, but perhaps later on the table definition might change, and then the script would break.

Comment: I see, so in case of two databases having the same column names or similar?

Comment: It's more just about not being clear what you want to select, and "everything" may change at some point.  Also, it wastes bandwidth to select every column when you only want to use one of them.  I will update my answer now.